# How is same dimension alone equivalent to isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Theorem: Two finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$ are isomorphic if and only if they have the dimension.

By isomorphic, my text means there exists an invertable linear map from one space to another.

Consider the vector spaces ${\mathbb Q}^3$ and ${\mathbb R}^3$.  They are both vector spaces with the same dimension.  Thus there must a 1-1 map from ${\mathbb Q}^3$ to ${\mathbb R}^3$.  But   ${\mathbb Q}^3$ is countable and ${\mathbb R}^3$ is uncountable.  So how can there exist such a 1-1 map?

Comment: They are not veftor spaces over the same $F$.

Comment: @RobertLewis Post as an answer.

Comment: oof. can’t believe i missed that.  thanks!

Comment: @EthanBolker:  typing something up right now--should post shortly.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a map can't exist, but it doesn't violate the theorem. The theorem says two vector spaces **over the same field $F$** are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension. And while $\mathbb Q^3$ and $\mathbb R^3$ have the same dimension, they are not over the same field.